# Electrum Bitcoin Wallet from Google Play Store

Tags: electrum, bitcoin-wallet-app, android

I recently found out that although the version was exactly the same, **the Electrum wallet downloaded from the Play Store is heavier than the app downloaded from the Electrum website**.

This raises the question of whether the Google Play Store is fundamentally trustworthy?
**Even though they are not verifiable right now.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the Electrum wallet downloaded from the Play Store is heavier than the app downloaded from the Electrum website.

Reason for difference in size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66419404/

So, you may see different size in Google Play Store based on Android device.

Example:

[image: Electrum-size-playstore]

> This raises the question of whether the Google Play Store is fundamentally trustworthy?

Best practices:

1. Do not trust Google Play Store
2. Build APK from source: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/contrib/android/Readme.md
3. If using APKs from https://electrum.org/#download, verify signatures. APKs are now reproducible since https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/pull/7263/ got merged
4. The binaries are not going to be byte-for-byte identical, as the official
   release is signed by a keystore that only the project maintainers have.
   You can use the `apkdiff.py` python script (written by the Signal developers) to compare
   the two binaries.

   ```
   $ python3 contrib/android/apkdiff.py Electrum_apk_that_you_built.apk Electrum_apk_official_release.apk
   ```

   This should output `APKs match!`